# Interpret double sum notation with one negative sum

Tags: summation, notation

Quick question, I am trying to interpret a double SUM notation where the first sum is negative. I don't know how to do it, so I'm asking you. Here's my equation:

$$
-\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^mp(M_i,C_j)logp(M_i|C_j)
$$

My **M** values are 4, namely **A,B,C,D** 
My **C** values are just the numbers from 1 to 4: **1,2,3,4**

Can somebody give me a very quick example of how that would look? So far I interpret it as (which might be totally wrong):

$$
p(A,1)*log(A|1) \quad \textrm{+} \quad p(A,2)*log(A|2) \quad \textrm{+} \quad p(A,3)*log(A|3) \quad \textrm{+} \quad p(A,4)*log(A|4) \\
p(B,1)*log(B|1) \quad \textrm{+} \quad p(B,2)*log(B|2) \quad \textrm{+} \quad p(B,3)*log(B|3) \quad \textrm{+} \quad p(B,4)*log(B|4)\\
...
\\
\quad \textrm{Please advice! Where do I put the MINUS of the first } \quad -\sum \quad \textrm{symbol in all this?} \quad $$

Comment: The minus is put just in front of everything!! $-\sum_{i=1}^4i=-(1+2+3+4)=-1-2-3-4$

Comment: thanks! That's what i thought but with my results it doesn't make sense.. hence I've made a mistake somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a minus sign in front of everything, and the reason that it's there is because your terms are all negative: they all have the form $p \log q$ for $0 < p,q < 1$, and the $\log q$ will be less than $0$.

If you prefer, we can rewrite the sum as
$$- \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m p(M_i, C_j) \log p(M_i \mid C_j) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m p(M_i,C_j) \log \frac1{p(M_i \mid C_j)}$$
which is a positive sum of positive terms.

Comment: Or even, put the sign *inside* the sum, which should be clearer......